# How can I prevent people from viewing my files when they browse my website?

Tags: web

How can I prevent people from viewing my files, when they browse my website?

I wish to prevent users from reading the files present at, say, `http://domainname.com/css/`. When they do that, all the files in that folder are visible to the user.

Comment: add css to folder WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions on that folder or move it out of public_html folder on server

Answer (score 0):

Put a dummy index.html file into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Apache web server, you can use the -Indexes option in your server configuration to disable directory indexing.